# How to get byte[] from float number

Tags: java, math

How to get byte[] from float number? I need to create message where for data I have four bytes, datum can be unsigned int( it is easy to get byte[] from int), binary and float ( but I don't know how to get four bytes from float ). Any solution ?

Answer (score 15):

You can use `Float.floatToRawIntBits(float)` but I suspect you don't need byte[] but instead want to be able to write to a stream of bytes. In which case I would use `DataOutputStream.writeFloat(float)`

If you are using NIO, you can use `ByteBuffer.putFloat()`  An advantage of ByteBuffer is that you can specify a ByteOrder with ByteBuffer.order() so you can handle either Big or Little endian.

Comment: +1, this is the best solution for writing floats over a data connection.

Answer (score 9):

Class `java.lang.Float` has methods `floatToIntBits()` and `floatToRawIntBits()` which you can use to get at the bit pattern of a `float` (as an `int`). So you could do something like this:

```
float value = 1.5e-3f;

int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(value);
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
bytes[0] = (byte)(bits & 0xff);
bytes[1] = (byte)((bits >> 8) & 0xff);
bytes[2] = (byte)((bits >> 16) & 0xff);
bytes[3] = (byte)((bits >> 24) & 0xff);
```

Note: You'd have to find out for your particular application which of `floatToIntBits()` or `floatToRawIntBits()` is appropriate and you'd have to determine in which order you need the bytes (little or big endian).

Answer (score 3):

Without any math involved, you can do that by writing the value via a `DataOutputStream` and then fetch the resulting output:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
dos.writeFloat(yourFloat);
byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
// at this point, your bytes will contain the 4-byte representation of the float.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think it's easy getting the bytes of an int, [`Float.floatToIntBits`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits%28float%29) is probably what you want:

```
float f = ...;
int i = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
byte[] floatBytes = toBytes(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                float f = 23f;
                byte[] op = new byte[4];
                int fi = Float.floatToIntBits(f);
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        int offset = (op.length - 1 - i) * 8;
                        op[i] = (byte) ((fi >>> offset) & 0xff);
                    }
                for(byte b : op)
                    {
                        System.out.format("0x%02X ", b);
                    }
            }
```